# What AAA is needed for? How is it secure?

Tags: routing

I have surfed the Internet and have not found much information 
about benefits of AAA. 
What is AAA? Do we have to use it? Is it kind of encryption? 
It is not clear to me.
Who can explain? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AAA is a big topic and this forum is not the place for a full discussion.  But briefly, AAA is a model for controlling access.  It specifies how clients (users) are identified (Authentication), what they are allowed to do (Authorization), and how the user's actions are monitored (Accounting). It also specifies the components (functions) for controlling access.

To answer your specific questions:
No, you don't have to use it.   You can use simple passwords on Cisco routers, for example.

AAA is not an encryption algorithm.  But encryption is often used as part of the authentication and authorization functions.

You can read more about AAA in articles like [*Network Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting: Part One*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/press/internet-protocol-journal/back-issues/table-contents-35/101-aaa-part1.html), by Sean Convery.

Comment: If you want to discuss this, we can always go to chat...

Comment: How can I access to chat? I dont know those details

Comment: Sorry. That was directed at @ronroyston

Answer (score 3):

Network access control is a security mechanism for controlling admission to networks
and resources. These controls enforce the security policy and employ rules about which
resources can be accessed. Network access control ensures the confidentiality and integrity
of the network resources.
The core of network access control forms the AAA framework, which consists of the
following:

■ Authentication establishes the user’s identity and access to the network resources.

■ Authorization describes what can be done and what can be accessed.

■ Accounting provides an audit trail of activities by logging the actions of the user.

Authentication, authorization, and accounting (AAA) are the network security services
that help manage the network access control on your network equipment. AAA provides
you with methods to secure access to network devices based on more granular techniques
than just IP addressing information. For example, you might have a requirement to control
access for a group of users regardless of their IP location. With AAA, you can integrate user
directories such as LDAP and AD so that groups of users can have the same access levels
decoupled from IP location. The implementation of AAA services requires authentication ;
however, authorization and accounting are optional services.

Answer (score -6):

AAA defines the model of gaining access to a network,e.g., 4gLTE connections, aDSL PPP, PPPoE cable modem, etc. AAA relates to network access (not application access, e.g. email or Facebook).

The *acronym* AAA is in measurable decline according to the below Google Trend Views.  Note the differences from perspectives of "computers" vs "telecom".

Higher layer (Web) security implementations are trending on the Authentication front, namely SSL/TLS (aka clientless VPN).  You see this as a preferred approach in WiFi and VPN access, for example (See Cisco AnyConnect Premium / "clientless SSL VPN").

[image]
[image]

Comment: I really don't understand your comment. It doesn't seem to relate to the question nor your answer.

Comment: I still cannot relate your 1099 to AAA.

Comment: I'm not the right person, and this is not the right place, to disparage Stack Exchange model. The correct place to bring it up is https://meta.stackexchange.com/. I wouldn't hold my breath about changing it, but I am supposed to work within it.

Comment: But, that _is_ the model. For instance, votes are supposed to be secret, but there are many on [so], and other sites, who insist that every down vote requires the voter to explain the vote. That would be the antithesis of a secret vote. I have no idea who voted down on your answer, and that is the way it is intended. People vote some of my answers down, but I _really don't care_ because that is everyone's right. You may think the voters are idiots, but everyone has the right to be an idiot. Complaining just seems to encourage that response.

Comment: You simply cannot force people to recognize your genius, nor can I force people to vote a certain way. It is their right to vote their conscience, and beliefs. That is the underlying SE model.

Comment: Someone voting is his or her prerogative, not vandalism. Vandalism is where someone maliciously edits and damages your post. That does not include editing to try to improve your post.